# ´Der Patient entwickelte Symptome einer Lebensmittelvergiftung´ - possible sentences?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, german-to-english

May I say the following sentences in German? I give the original English sentences (the following are the translations I´ve got from German native speakers, but I am not sure whether they are possible since I am a non-native speaker. )

> Der Patient entwickelte Symptome einer Lebensmittelvergiftung? (The patient developed the symptoms of food poisoning.)
>
> Das Dach des Tunnels leckte Wasser. (The roof of the tunnel was seeping water)
>
> Diese Straße trägt einen großen Teil von Verkehr. (This road carries a good deal of traffic)
>
> Dieser Raum wird 200 oder mehr Dollar führen. (The room will run 200 dollars or more.)

Please, just say whether it is possible to construct these sentences in German or they are nonsense.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for proofreading. Moreover the sentences do not seem to have any connection. To make your question on-topic, point out a special aspect you are interested in or are having difficulties wtih.

Comment: I´am sorry I don´t think I am asking for proofreading, I can delete the English sentences. I did not translate these sentences, it was my German respondends who did it. I just want to know, as a non-native speaker of German, if the Germans really can say these sentences, that´s all. I need just to hear- I think this sentence is nonsense, we do not say it this way or it is OK. And yes, the sentences are not connected, but I am asking whether these sentences are possible in the German language, that´s the point which interconnects them.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft from previous posts of the OP I believe we are not faced with a proof-reading post here. To my understanding the sentences given should merely be examples on how  things are said in German vs English. The English sentences are not to proof a translation was correct but to see differences, or similarities. This is more of a lingustic question but this alone should not make it off topic here even more so if they needed a deeper knowledge of German.

Comment: I'm voting to close because there is no central topic in this question, it's unlikely to help future visitors and it's multiple.

Comment: Unzulässige Sammelfrage. Das ist x-mal erklärt worden, wieso Sammelfragen ein Ärgernis sind.

Answer (score 3):

> Der Patient entwickelte *Symptome* einer Lebensmittelvergiftung.

I think you just missed the noun *Symptome (symptoms)* here.

> Das Dach des Tunnels *tropfte*.

The term *leckte Wasser* is not that much used in german as far as I know. A commonly used synonym is the verb *tropfen*.

> *Diese* Straße trägt einen großen Teil *des* Verkehr*s*.

*Straße* is a female noun so it's the female pronoun *Diese*.

> Dieser Raum wird 200 oder Mehr Dollar führen.

I'm not quite sure what this sentence is supposed to mean. Does it mean that the room will cost 200$ or does the room will produce 200$ income? Generally this sentence doesn't make much sence.

Comment: Or: `Im Dach des Tunnels war ein Leck.` I agree that the sentence on the $200 doesn't make much sense. And I don't understand it in English either ;)

Comment: @Basti Funck: Can you really say Das Dach des Tunnels tropfte.? Is this sentence OK in German? And I corrected my type-errors , please consider the sentences not from the grammatical point of view, but rather consider if you could say these sentences generally. And in the last sentence, both explanations are possible (cost and produce income, it depends who says it- eg. owner of the room or the one who buys/rents it)

Comment: Ein Dach, ein Rohr, eine Wanne können schon "lecken": *Aus dem Rohr leckte eine grüne Flüssigkeit* - *Das Dach des Tunnels leckte* - *Aus dem Dach des Tunnels leckte Wasser*

Answer (score 1):

1.)

> Der Patient entwickelte einer Lebensmittelvergiftung?

I'm not a doctor, so this might be how doctors talk about it, however *eine Krankheit entwickeln* (*developing a illness*) feels wrong. Also your native speaker completely ignored that it's about the symptoms, not the actual illness (symptoms that fit illness A might actually be caused by illness B!). *Entwickeln* does fit *Symptome* if you are talking about an ongoing process (even if it's in the past and at this time already complete). If you want to express that, when examining the patient, certain symptoms were found (that had developed before the examination), you'd go with *zeigen* instead:

> Der Patient entwickelte die Symptome einer Lebensmittelvergiftung.
>
> Der Patient zeigte die Symptome einer Lebensmittelvergiftung.

2.)

> Das Dach des Tunnels leckte Wasser.

*Wasser lecken* sound a bit odd, because *lecken* already included water/liquid (in case of other things it can be specified, for example *Gasleck* or *Ölleck*). That said, I don't think *lecken* is the correct word to use in the first place - *lecken* means *to leak*. *Seeping* however is something a bit different, in most cases better translated as *sickern*, that has the implication of water/a liquid seeping through natural materials like earth, stone, sand, etc. (while *lecken* implies the liquid escaping from/through a man-made container/barrier like pipes). A sugested transpation for your sentence would be.

> Wasser sickerte durch die Tunneldecke

If you just want to express what you actually can see without implying how the water got there (humidity? broken pipes? aliens?) you could got for a neutral

> An der Tunneldecke hatte sich Wasser gebildet
>
> Water had formed on the ceiling of the tunnel

3.)

> Dieser Straße trägt einen großen Teil von Verkehr.

Sound ok, although it would be *vom Verkehr*, not *von* (or if you want to be more gramatically correct you can use the Genitiv *des Verkehrs*. *Den Verkehr tragen* ist ok, although you can make it sound a bit better by saying

> Die Straße trägt einen großen Teil der Verkehrslast.

Because *tragen* in this context implies some form of burden/weight (*Last*), which we can add to *Verkehr*

4.)

> Dieser Raum wird 200 oder Mehr Dollar führen.

Sounds wrong. As I understand *run* in this context means *to cost*, which would be translated to *kosten*, not *führen*. I don't have the context, but if this is about a room you rent at a hotel, *room* would be better translated as *Zimmer*, not *Raum*. Possible translations would be:

> Dieses Zimmer wird 200 dollar oder mehr kosten
>
> Das Zimmer wird mindestens 200 dollar kosten
>
> Das Zimmer kostet ab 200 dollar aufwärts

The last phrase *ab X aufwärts* expresses a base price and implies that it can be more depending on the customers wishes, selection options, additional services, etc.